# Center image within relative div

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I've got a `relative` div. Within this div I would like to center the image (so the face of the dog is visible). How could I do this?

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tailwindcss/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


 <div class="relative h-24 overflow-hidden">
  <img class="absolute w-full h-auto" src="https://www.petmd.com/sites/default/files/Acute-Dog-Diarrhea-47066074.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: i'd remove the `img` tag, and use the `background-image` css property on your "relative" div (like this https://jsfiddle.net/mpgbd6fw/)

Comment: as image has position absolute , you can use top with negative value to set position with div, - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/arOpZJ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add these styles to your `img`

```
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tailwindcss/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


 <div class="relative h-24 overflow-hidden">
  <img style="top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%);" class="absolute w-full h-auto" src="https://www.petmd.com/sites/default/files/Acute-Dog-Diarrhea-47066074.jpg" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just putting in the CSS file or style of the image:

```
img {
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
div {
  background-image: url('https://www.petmd.com/sites/default/files/Acute-Dog-Diarrhea-47066074.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /* background size makes it full width */
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tailwindcss/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


 <div class="relative h-24 overflow-hidden">
 
</div>
```

This uses css to put the image inside the div as background. This is something i like to use.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use top with negative value as image position is absolute

```css
div{
  position: relative;
}

img{
  position: absolute;
  top: -220px; 
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tailwindcss/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


 <div class="relative h-24 overflow-hidden">
  <img class="absolute w-full h-auto" src="https://www.petmd.com/sites/default/files/Acute-Dog-Diarrhea-47066074.jpg" />
</div>
```